# RobotFramework: Run Suits in Parallel instead of Test Cases

Tags: robotframework

I have 8 different suits. For example suit names are: [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]. Below will be my pabot run command:

pabot --pabotlib A.txt B.txt C.txt....and so on.

I want to run the Suits in Parallel, but test cases should run in Serial. I want that if I open 8 browsers, each suit should run in 1 browser (running test cases serially). Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that how pabot already works? If each of those suites opens a browser, you'll have 8 browsers. Robot by default runs tests serially within a suite.

Comment: By default, pabot uses as many processes as you have CPU's available. For instance, if you have a quad core processor, it uses 4 processes by default. This can be changed by using `--processes 8` flag in your `pabot` command. Example: `pabot --processes 8 tests/`

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley, I was using --teslevelsplit that why my test cases were running parallel. removing --testlevelsplit resolved my problem

Comment: Thanks for the information @asprtrmp